# Integral of $(n−[n])\sin(nx)$: Bounded or Not?

Tags: integration, upper-lower-bounds

[There is same question, but](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2249449/is-there-any-conditions-for-a-function-to-be-derivative-function) I want to check only one subtle thing from the problem.

Is $\int_1^N (n-[n])\sin(nx)\,dn$ bounded for all $N$ with $0<x<2\pi$?

(Here, $[n]$ is greatest integer function.)

It is seemingly certain, but I can't prove it.

Comment: Do you want the integral to be bounded for each $N$, or to be uniformly bounded in both $x$ and $N$?

Answer (score 1):

If we fix $N$ then
$$\left| \int_1^N \big(n-[n]\big) \sin(nx) \right| \,\Bbb dn \leq \int_1^N (1 \cdot 1) \,\Bbb dn = N-1 $$
that is because $\big|\sin(nx)\big| \le 1$ and $\big|n - [n]\big| \le 1$.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but would you clear some notation please?

Comment: Good, but last inequality doesn't seem correct...

Comment: Why what seems to be the problem in the last inequality? 0≤|x-[x]| <1 is always true, are trying to say he messed up in the less than equal to sign?